# Javascript map operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, array-map

I have an object like this

```js
[
  {
    _id: '5ef34e92858bff53bcf69e11',
    factors: [ {factor_id:'factor_id1',calmode:'calmode1',desc:'desc1',webserv:'webserv1',approach:'approach1'},
               {factor_id:'factor_id2',calmode:'calmode2',desc:'desc2',webserv:'webserv2',approach:'approach2'}, 
               {factor_id:'factor_id3',calmode:'calmode3',desc:'desc3',webserv:'webserv3',approach:'approach3'} 
             ],
    clientId: 'Company1',
    module: 'Mod1',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ef350c9c1acd61e58ef9d08',
    factors: [ {factor_id:'factor_id4',calmode:'calmode4',desc:'desc4',webserv:'webserv4',approach:'approach4'}, 
               {factor_id:'factor_id5',calmode:'calmode5',desc:'desc5',webserv:'webserv5',approach:'approach5'}
             ],
    clientId: 'Company1',
    module: 'Mod2',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I want to create a final list like below

_id, ClientId,module,factor_id,calmode,desc,webserv,approach

I am trying to use map operator within another map operator but its not coming out properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const tmpFacLst = FacExists.map((module) => {
        const Factor = {
          module_id: module._id,
          module: module.module,
        };
        return Factor;
        /*const Fac = module.factors.map((factor)=>{
          const FactorDtl = {
            factor_id:factor._id,
            factor_desc: factor.desc
          }
          return FactorDtl;
        })*/
      });
```

**Update:**  I am able to achieve using loop

```
const result = [];
  FacExists.forEach((item) => {
    const Factors = item.factors;
    Factors.forEach((Subitem) => {
      const Facobj = {
        _id: item._id,
        ClientId: item.clientId,
        module: item._id,
        factor_id: Subitem._id,
        calmode: Subitem.calmode,
        desc: Subitem.desc,
        webserv: Subitem.webserv,
      };
      result.push(Facobj);
    });
  });
```

I want to know is there any better way of doing this without looping.

Comment: Your first snippet is broken, it appears you don't have the data for Factor. Could you please paste that in?

Comment: *not coming out properly* - how's it coming it out exactly? Please add it in the question.

Comment: Now I have expanded factors object.  I am getting [undefined,undefined] if I return it within the second map operator. If return within the first map operator I am getting the Factor array as it is. I don't want to loop. Please let me know if you need more info. I will also try other options from my end.

Answer (score 1):

An approach like this should work:

```js
const items = [
  {
    _id: "5ef34e92858bff53bcf69e11",
    factors: [
      {
        factor_id: 2,
        calmode: "cal",
        desc: "something",
        webserv: "10.0.0.0",
        approach: "forwards",
      },
    ],
    clientId: "Company1",
    module: "Mod1",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "5ef350c9c1acd61e58ef9d08",
    factors: [
      {
        factor_id: 3,
        calmode: "cal",
        desc: "something",
        webserv: "10.0.0.1",
        approach: "forwards",
      },
    ],
    clientId: "Company1",
    module: "Mod2",
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const result = [];
items.forEach((item) => {
  const { factors, __v, ...rest } = item;
  result.push(...factors.map((factor) => ({ ...factor, ...rest })));
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am getting lot of meta data with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
 const finalResult = FacExists.reduce((aggregator,fact) => {
      let result =   fact.factors.map(fac=>{
          return {
             _id: fact._id,
             clientId: fact.clientId,
             module: fact.module,
             
             ...fac
          }})
aggregator = [...aggregator,...result];
return aggregator
  },[]);
```

you will get the desired result in the "finalResult" variable.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am getting two undefined objects.

Comment: can you please share the result which you are getting

Comment: Here is the result when I printed the object in console [ undefined, undefined ]. I think its expected as nothing is returned from the outer map iteration.

Comment: @AnanthVivek I have edited my answer. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to clean your question up a bit because you have the `Object` keyword / class listed as elements of your `factors` array, which you call an "object". You should include those objects in your snippets.

```js
let notAnObj = [
  {
    _id: '5ef34e92858bff53bcf69e11',
    factors: [ {_id: 1234, desc: 'bob loblaw'}],
    clientId: 'Company1',
    module: 'Mod1',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ef350c9c1acd61e58ef9d08',
    factors: [],
    clientId: 'Company1',
    module: 'Mod2',
    __v: 0
  }
]
   console.log(notAnObject)
```

```js
let arr= [
  {
    _id: '5ef34e92858bff53bcf69e11',
    factors: [ {_id: 1234, desc: 'bob loblaw'}],
    clientId: 'Company1',
    module: 'Mod1',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5ef350c9c1acd61e58ef9d08',
    factors: [],
    clientId: 'Company1',
    module: 'Mod2',
    __v: 0
  }
]

      const tmpFacLst = arr.map((obj) => {
        return {
          _id: obj._id, 
          ClientId: obj.clientId,
          module: obj.module,
          factors: obj.factors.map(factor => {
            return {
              _id: factor._id,
              desc: factor.desc,
            }
          }),
          calmode: undefined,
          webserv: undefined,
          approach: undefined
        };
      });
      console.log(tmpFacLst)
```

Comment: with this I am getting the object which is similar to my original object

Comment: @AnanthVivek You're missing some sort of reduction (.reduce) or something in your logic. .map is designed to return an array of the same size containing whatever values you place in the object that is returned. I don't understand what the goal is. What does the final schema look like?